# How do I add buttons that accept delete and clear orders on my webpage with the use of arrays?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, dom-events, rendering

I have to create a webpage that can add and delete and clear orders inside the textbox with the application of arrays. The conditions are as follows:

1.Initially, there should be no element/value inside the array of the program.

- The value/element will be deleted once the Delete Order Button is clicked.
- It will only contain a value when the Add Order button is clicked.

2. If someone inputs a value and clicks "Add Order"

- It must add the value inside the array of the program
- An alert box shows up saying "Order has been added".
- The order should also be displayed in the second cell of the table under the "Order:" text

3.If someone inputs a value and clicks "Delete Order"

- The added value in the array must be deleted
- An alert box must be displayed saying "Order has been deleted".
- The inputted order should also be deleted in the second cell of the table under the "Order:" text.

4.If someone clicks "Clear input"

- The content of the textbox should be erased

Although I've learned the concepts of Arrays I don't have an idea on how to apply that into making this website. I've already set up the alerts and layout but was unable to make the orders pop up onto the second cell on the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
     <head>
    <style>
   body {background-color: #a8f00e;} 
   table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fff714;
  text-align: center;    
  }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>

   <body>
     <h1>Point of Sale Program</h1>
   <table style="width:100%">
   <tr>
  <th>
  <h2> Add Order
  <br> 
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input type="text"> 
   <br>
  <button onclick="Add()">Add Order</button>
  <button onclick="Delete()">Delete Order</button>
   <button type="reset" value="Reset">Clear Input</button>
 </h2>
  </th>

<th>Order</th> 

  <script>
  function Add() {
    alert("Order had been added");
  } 
  function Delete() {
    alert("Order had been deleted");
  }   
  </script>  

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: if there are no open questions you might consider accepting the answer which was most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You define your array like that `var itemArray = []`

then you add items to your array via `itemArray.push('Item Name')`
and remove items of an array via the `splice()` method
to just clear your array you re-declare it like that `itemArray = []`

Hope that helps getting you started!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you're after? or do you need the form so you can send the information on?

```
<h1>Point of Sale Program</h1>
<table id="OrdersTable" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><h2>Add Order</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="OrderName">
            </td>
            <td> 
                <button id="AddButton">Add</button>
                <button id="ClearInputButton">Clear</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><button onclick="clearAllOrders()">Clear Orders</button></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<script>

    // Orders Array
    var orders = [];

    // Adds order to Array
    function addOrder(text){
        orders.push(text);
        alert("Order has been added");
        drawOrders();
    }

    // Removes order based on position in array
    function removeOrder(index){
        orders.splice(index,1);
        alert("Order has been deleted");
        drawOrders();
    }

    // Removes all orders from the Array
    function clearAllOrders(){
        orders = [];
        drawOrders();
    }

    // Draw/Redraw the orders into the table
    function drawOrders(){
        // Select the Body of the table or <tbody></tbody>
        var tableBody = document.querySelector("#OrdersTable tbody");
        // clear the table body
        var body = tableBody.innerHTML = "";
        // Then add all the orders into the table body
        orders.forEach((order,index)=>{
            let deletebutton = document.createElement("button");
            deletebutton.innerText = "Delete";
            deletebutton.onclick = function(){removeOrder(index)}; 
            let row = document.createElement("tr");
            let firstCell = document.createElement("td");
            firstCell.innerText = order;
            let secondCell = document.createElement("td");
            secondCell.appendChild(deletebutton);
            row.appendChild(firstCell);
            row.appendChild(secondCell);
            tableBody.appendChild(row);
        });
    }
    // Attach onclick event to Add button and empty the textbox when order is added 
    document.querySelector("#AddButton").onclick = function(){
        var textInput = document.querySelector("#OrderName");
        addOrder(textInput.value);
        textInput.value = "";
    }
    // Attach onclick event to clear input button so when it's clicked the textbox is emptied 
    document.querySelector("#ClearInputButton").onclick = function(){
        document.querySelector('#OrderName').value = "";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: As long as it applies arrays like the scenario asks then it’s all good

Comment: yep, in the code snippet it maintains the array called orders

Answer (score 0):

```js
const itemTemplateHtml = `<li>
  <span data-item>Invalid Item</span>
  <button type="button" data-delete-item>Delete Item</button>
</li>`;
let itemTemplate;

function emptyElementNode(elmNode) {
  Array
    .from(elmNode.childNodes)
    .forEach(node => node.remove());
}
function createTemplateFromCode(templateHtml) {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  container.innerHTML = templateHtml;

  return container.firstElementChild;
}

function logListOrderData(orderList, elmFormOrders) {
  // console.clear();
  console.log('orderList :', JSON.stringify(orderList));
  console.log('elmFormOrders.value :', elmFormOrders.value);
  console.log('\n');
}

function updateOrderListFormData(elmOrderList, elmFormOrders) {
  const orderList = Array
    .from(elmOrderList.children)
    .reduce((list, elm) =>
      list.concat(
        elm.querySelector('[data-item]').dataset.value.trim() || []
      ), []
    );
  elmFormOrders.value = orderList.join(',');

  logListOrderData(orderList, elmFormOrders);
}

function addOrderListItem(value, elmOrderList, elmFormOrders) {
  // value = value.replace((/,/g), "\\,");

  const elmListItem = itemTemplate.cloneNode(true);
  const elmDataItem = elmListItem.querySelector('[data-item]');

  elmDataItem.dataset.value = value;
  elmDataItem.textContent = value;
  elmListItem
    .querySelector('[data-delete-item]')
    .addEventListener('click', handleDeleteItemWithBoundContext.bind({
      elmListItem,
      elmOrderList,
      elmFormOrders
    }));
  elmOrderList.appendChild(elmListItem);

  updateOrderListFormData(elmOrderList, elmFormOrders);
}

function handleAddItemWithBoundContext(/*evt*/) {
  const { elmOrderItem, elmOrderList, elmFormOrders } = this;
  
  const value = elmOrderItem.value.trim();
  elmOrderItem.value = value;

  if (value !== '') {
    addOrderListItem(value, elmOrderList, elmFormOrders);
  }
}
function handleDeleteItemWithBoundContext(/*evt*/) {
  const { elmListItem, elmOrderList, elmFormOrders } = this;

  elmListItem.remove();

  updateOrderListFormData(elmOrderList, elmFormOrders);
}
function handleClearOrdersWithBoundContext(/*evt*/) {
  const { elmOrderItem, elmOrderList, elmFormOrders } = this;

  elmOrderItem.value = '';
  elmFormOrders.value = '';

  emptyElementNode(elmOrderList);

  updateOrderListFormData(elmOrderList, elmFormOrders);
}


function initializeAddItem(elmAddItem, elmOrderItem, elmOrderList, elmFormOrders) {
  elmAddItem.addEventListener('click', handleAddItemWithBoundContext.bind({
    elmOrderItem,
    elmOrderList,
    elmFormOrders,
  }));
}
function initializeClearOrders(elmClearOrders, elmOrderItem, elmOrderList, elmFormOrders) {
  if (elmClearOrders) {
    elmClearOrders.addEventListener('click', handleClearOrdersWithBoundContext.bind({
      elmOrderItem,
      elmOrderList,
      elmFormOrders,
    }));
  }
}

function initializeOrders() {
  const elmOrders = document.querySelector('#orders');

  const elmOrderItem = elmOrders.querySelector('[data-order-item]');
  const elmAddItem = elmOrders.querySelector('[data-add-item]');

  const elmOrdersForm = elmOrderItem && elmAddItem && elmOrders.querySelector('form');

  const elmOrderList = elmOrdersForm && elmOrdersForm.querySelector('.order-list');
  const elmFormOrders = elmOrdersForm && elmOrdersForm.querySelector('[data-form-orders]');

  itemTemplate = elmOrderList && elmFormOrders && createTemplateFromCode(itemTemplateHtml);
  if (itemTemplate) {

    initializeAddItem(elmAddItem, elmOrderItem, elmOrderList, elmFormOrders);
    initializeClearOrders(
      elmOrders.querySelector('[data-clear-orders]'),
      elmOrderItem, elmOrderList, elmFormOrders
    );

    updateOrderListFormData(elmOrderList, elmFormOrders);
  }
}

/*export default */initializeOrders();
```

```css
body { background-color: #a8f00e; font-size: x-small; }
h1, h2 { margin: 0; font-size: unset;}
button, textarea, [type="text"] { font-size: x-small; }
article, fieldset, li { position: relative; }
button { position: absolute; right: 5px; }
li button { bottom: 2px; }
article > button { right: 9px; } 
form { margin-bottom: 7px; }
ol {
  margin: -1px 3px 5px 2px; padding: 0 0 0 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fff714;
}
ol:empty { border: none; }
li { margin: 0 0 0 10px; padding: 4px 0 5px 0; }
#orders { width: 40%; }

.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%!important; 
  width: 59%;
  top: 0;
  left: auto!important;
  right: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<h1>Point of Sale Program</h1>

<article id="orders">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Place an Order</legend>

    <input type="text" data-order-item placeholder="Put an Order Item" />
    <button type="button" data-add-item>Add Item</button>
  </fieldset>

  <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
    <ol class='order-list'></ol>
    <input type="hidden" name="order_list" data-form-orders value="" />
  </form>

  <button type="reset" data-clear-orders>Clear Order List</button>
</article>
```